# i am doing a project to predict age and gender using tensorflow and opencv. and how to add path for xml file

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras

I am facing an error -
File "", line 159, in 
main()

File "", line 155, in main
face.detect_face()
OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

the code is

def detect_face(self):
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.CASE_PATH)

```
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # infinite loop, break by key ESC
    while True:
        if not video_capture.isOpened():
            sleep(5)
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.2,
            minNeighbors=10,
            minSize=(self.face_size, self.face_size)
        )
```

or the full code is  [here](https://github.com/ashubansal005/Gender_and_Age_Recognition/blob/master/real_demo)

after searching so many answers I think this is an issue of OpenCV version or the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml file is not loaded. but I am not find any solution.
please help me.

Comment: also when I run the real_demo file, the front camera automatically on.

Comment: i also had tried this path. --C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml